# Sqlite3 not reading from database

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlite

I have a database with two columns .One is a primary key auto increment and another is a column for urls. the first is named 'id' and second is named 'longurls'. I have runned the following code to retrieve a 'id' record where longurls = 'X' value .

```
import sqlite3
long_url = 'http://www.google.com'
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT id FROM stuff WHERE longurls=?",(long_url,))
k = c.fetchall()
for stuff in k:
    id = stuff[0]
print (id)
```

[This is a picture showing the url exists in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFwy4.png). Only 'none' is printed

Comment: Also `print ('id')` won't print the variable `id`, it will actually print the string `"id"` : ) And this is probably a indentation issue because `print` lives outside of the `for` loop.

Comment: sorry just a mistake while typing the Q.

Answer (score 0):

I've not yet used sqlite in Python but the bit of your code that looks strange to me is

```
for stuff in k:
    id = stuff[0]
print (id)
```

what happens if you define id outside the loop?

```
id = 0
for stuff in k:
    id = stuff[0]
print (id)
```

If you could return a list of ids then this will need further modification

Comment: the error remains the same. as it loops through the for loop it updates the value of id. so we can use it outside the loop

Comment: Sorry, still drinking my first coffee. After reading your comment, I have edited my code to stop it just printing the string id and to have the id outside of the loop which is down to the scope in the snippet.